# How run a command on an EC2 instance? AWS-RunShellScript is missing from SSM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ssm, amazon-systems-manager

In the AWS Console, I opened the AWS Systems Manager Console. I then chose "Run Command" and clicked the "Run a command" button.

The only commands it has are:

```
AWS-ApplyAnsiblePlaybooks   Amazon  Linux
AWS-ApplyChefRecipes    Amazon  Windows, Linux
AWS-ApplyDSCMofs    Amazon  Windows
AWS-ApplyPatchBaseline  Amazon  Windows
AWS-ConfigureAWSPackage Amazon  Windows, Linux
AWS-ConfigureCloudWatch Amazon  Windows
AWS-ConfigureDocker Amazon  Windows, Linux
AWS-ConfigureWindowsUpdate  Amazon  Windows
AWS-FindWindowsUpdates  Amazon  Windows
AWS-InstallApplication  Amazon  Windows
```

Where did the `AWS-RunShellScript` command go? Is there another way i can test running a command on an EC2 instance ***that I have not opened up for inbound internet traffic***?

Comment: Did you find AWS-RunShellScript? if it is still missing, which region?

Answer (score 0):

There are **multiple pages** of commands available.

Either click the arrow (`>`) in the top-right of the list to view more commands, or type the name of the command in the search field.

It's not that obvious in the UI. Feel free to submit Feedback (bottom-left corner of the console) if you think the UI should be improved.

[image: Systems Manager Run Command]

Comment: The arrow is grayed out. It says it has one page

Comment: Click the right-facing `>` arrow. Trust me, it works. Alternatively, put `AWS-RunShellScript` in the search box and hit Enter.

Comment: I did put it in the search box and got nothing